Default constructible class expected, but only parametrised constructor is meaningful
I have this hard requirement that one of my classes, ClassX is instantiated in a reflective manner by a third party module Modul3P, calling ClassX's default constructor. Then, Modul3P calls one of the instance's method, aMethod():
//inaccessible, approximate code
void Modul3P(String className) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    InterfaceX object = (InterfaceX) clazz.newInstance();
    object.aMethod();
}
interface InterfaceX {
    void aMethod();
}

My ClassX, however, depends badly on a parameter to be properly set up:
class ClassX implements InterfaceX {
    ClassX(Object param){...} //required for proper setup   
    ClassX(){...};            //called by Modul3P
    void aMethod(){...}
}

How do I overcome this issue?
My failed attempt (with Javassist) was to create a proper instance inst, then create on-the-fly a class derived from ClassX, which can be default-initialised, and which during initialisation would be injected inst:
class ClassX implements InterfaceX {
   //...
   Class<? extends ClassX> defaultConstructibleOnTheFlyClass(){...}
}
//...
ClassX inst = new ClassX(aParam); //proper initialisation
Modul3P(inst.defaultConstructibleOnTheFlyClass().getName());


Quite ugly, but this idiom can work in otherwise intractable situations:
class ClassX implements InterfaceX {
  // (ThreadLocal in case multithreaded access is a concern.)
  public static final ThreadLocal<Gorp> tl = new ThreadLocal<>();
  private final Gorp param;
  public ClassX() {
    this(tl.get());
    tl.remove(); // if you want
  }
  public ClassX(Gorp param) {
    super();
    this.param = param;
  }
  @Override // InterfaceX
  public void aMethod() {
    // use this.param
  }
}

// Somewhere else, prior to Modul3P instantiating your ClassX, on the same thread:

ClassX.tl.set(gorpFromSomewhere);


Would be a genuine use case for ScopedValue once it becomes a part of the standard Java API.

Yes, or Flexible Constructor Bodies (https://openjdk.org/jeps/482).

Maybe you should use the Factory pattern. This is easier to maintain and extend than using reflection:
public interface Builder<T> {
  T createObject(String param);
}

public class MyFactory {
  Map m = new HashMap<String, Builder>();
  public void addBuilder(String str, Builder b) {
    ... // add the str / builder pair to the map
  }
  public Object create (String builderName, String param) {
    Builder b = m.get(builderName);
    if (b == null) throw ...
    return b.createObject(param);
  }
}

Using this framework, all you need to do is create a Builder as an intermediary for creating your Object, add the builder to the Factory, and use the Factory to build the Object

ClassX is instantiated through reflection in Modul3P, I cannot change that.
